# Tracking users on internet

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, tracking

We want to track users when they visits our competitor websites.

Suppose the user visits a.com(our site) and then visits b.com and c.com (our competitors) , we want to know the user has visited those sites. Is there a way to track this without using plugins like chrome extensions.

I know there is limitation in cookies. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Thankfully, no.**

From time to time accidental mechanisms to leak such information become known (such as, at one time, it was [possible to inspect link styles to see if it's visited](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy)). **Such things are regarded as serious security breaches and are swiftly eliminated by browser vendors.**

[Basic web security principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) isolate the interaction with unrelated domains, unless both web pages willingly try to talk to each other. Furthermore, if a user visits your site first and the closes it, their interaction with you is finished - in no sane scenario would you be able to know what they do atferwards.

*Not to mention the obvious fact that what you're asking is just plain highly unethical.*

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can get your competitors to give you access to their websites, either through include scripts or indirectly if you manage to track users through ad-networks or Facebook pings, it's not possible. You cannot access (should not be able, in any case) cookies set by another domain.

Some browsers allow access to the previously visited URL through `document.referrer` -- but that is not guaranteed to work, nor is reliable. In short, there's no way of doing it targeted.

Not being able to easily track people is a good thing; but it makes constructions like the on you are wanting a lot harder.